# Where is my response and how i know the status of my response

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, http-post, response

I written a code to call an api.. but unable to understand what is the response  for the same:

```
    string secret = "=";
    string clientToken = "4xob3emhc";
    string accessToken = "akab-igw754pqdtlw6glf-2sjroprise6arn2h";
    string apiurl = "https://akab-7t4r7lq3a7d7-js5q6mdtx42qimcn.purge.akamaiapis.net/ccu/v3/invalidate/url/production";
    List<string> headers = new List<string>();
    string httpMethod = "POST";
    string outputfile = null;
    string data = "{\"hostname\": \"www.qa.wo.com\",\"objects\": [\"www.qa.wo.com/getmedia/9931b92a-c7f3-4a71-ab27-37e2b13572c0/should-be-here.jpg?width=2541&height=1811&ext=.jpg\"]}";
    int maxBodySize = 2048;

    EdgeGridV1Signer signer = new EdgeGridV1Signer(null, maxBodySize);
    ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientToken, accessToken, secret);

    Stream uploadStream = null;
    uploadStream = new MemoryStream(data.ToByteArray());

    var uri = new Uri(apiurl);
    var request = WebRequest.Create(uri);

    foreach (string header in headers) request.Headers.Add(header);
    request.Method = httpMethod;

    Stream output = Console.OpenStandardOutput();
    if (outputfile != null)
        output = new FileInfo(outputfile).OpenWrite();

    signer.Sign(request, credential, uploadStream);

    using (var result = signer.Execute(request, credential, uploadStream))
    {
        using (output)
        {
            using (result)
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 1024];
                int bytesRead = 0;


                while ((bytesRead = result.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
                {
                    output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Can u tell me where i see the response of the web api call?

I cannot find any statuscode in result object? where else it should be?

I am trying to find whether the akamai purge happend or not.

I have converted this code from code written for console application. looks like they are writting to console, but how i can see the response at runtime instead of console. Basically i am looking for status is "success"

Comment: You have few dependencies such as EdgeGridV1Signer. Without knowing those, it is not easy to see what the code is doing.

Comment: https://github.com/akamai-open/AkamaiOPEN-edgegrid-C-Sharp please see here

Comment: Note this comment from MSDN _"As a rule, when you use an IDisposable object, you should declare and instantiate it in a using statement."_. The way you have the embedded using statements (particularly using(result) when it is already in the outer using statement) may give you problems. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

Comment: any idea what is the fix?